Apache Ignite Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms
My requirement is, I need to create standalone Apache Ignite thick client running like a server. And there is a client application that will access the Ignite.
I managed to run my Ignite server in openshift environment using KubernetesIpFinder given my namespace and servicename.
When I try to run my Ignite client in openshift using KubernetesIpFinder given same namespace and servicename, I am getting "Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms" Error.
NOTE: Cluster role and binding access already been given.
Below are my details and code
I am using

Spring Boot version :  3.1.5
Gradle : 8.4 (Wrapper)
Apache Ignite: 2.15.0

SERVER CODE:
    @Bean
    public IgniteConfigurer configurer() {
        return igniteConfig -> {
            igniteConfig.setIgniteInstanceName("myCache");
            igniteConfig.setMetricsLogFrequency(600000); // 10 minutes
            igniteConfig.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
            igniteConfig.setDiscoverySpi(getTcpDiscoverySpi());
            var communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
            communicationSpi.setMessageQueueLimit(100);
            communicationSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(1000);
            igniteConfig.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);

            igniteConfig.setCacheConfiguration(getCacheConfiguration());

        };
    }

    private TcpDiscoverySpi getTcpDiscoverySpi() {
        var spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

        var kubConfiguration = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
        kubConfiguration.setNamespace("option-services");
        kubConfiguration.setServiceName("test-ignite-cache-service");

        var ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(kubConfiguration);
        spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        // set timeout properties
        spi.setAckTimeout(90000);
        spi.setSocketTimeout(90000);
        spi.setNetworkTimeout(90000);
        return spi;
    }
    private <K, V> CacheConfiguration<K, V> getCacheConfiguration( ) {
        CacheConfiguration<K, V> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        cacheCfg.setName("marketCache");
         cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        return cacheCfg;
    }

route.yaml
----------
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 600s
  name: test-ignite-cache-service
  namespace: option-services
  labels:
    app: test-ignite-cache-service
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: test-ignite-cache-service
  port:
    targetPort: 8080
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
  wildcardPolicy: None

service.yaml
-----------

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-ignite-cache-service
  namespace: option-services
  labels:
    app: test-ignite-cache-service
spec:
  selector:
    deploymentconfig: test-ignite-cache-service
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: 10800-thinclient
      port: 10800
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 10800
      nodePort: 30800
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}


deploymentconfig.yaml
----------------------

apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: test-ignite-cache-service
  labels:
    app: test-ignite-cache-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    deploymentConfig: test-ignite-cache-service
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
    recreateParams:
      timeoutSeconds: 600
  triggers: [ ]
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-ignite-cache-service
      labels:
        deploymentConfig: test-ignite-cache-service
        app: test-ignite-cache-service
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 75
      serviceAccountName: test-ignite-cache-service
      containers:
        - name: test-ignite-cache-service
          image: {{ .Values.lsImageBase }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: JAVA_VM_OPTS
              value: "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.healthCheckEndpoint }}
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 200
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.healthCheckEndpoint }}
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 200
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - name: thinclient
              containerPort: 10800
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: {{ .Values.minMemory }}
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: {{ .Values.maxMemory }}
              cpu: "500m"


CLIENT CODE:
 @Bean
    public Ignite igniteC() {
        System.out.println("ignite bean service");

        Ignite ignite = null;
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);
        try {

            igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(getTcpDiscoverySpi());

            TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
            commSpi.setLocalPort(42100);
            commSpi.setMessageQueueLimit(1024);
            commSpi.setSocketWriteTimeout(10000L);
            igniteConfiguration.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);
            igniteConfiguration.setFailureDetectionTimeout(90000);

            igniteConfiguration.setIncludeEventTypes();
            igniteConfiguration.setPublicThreadPoolSize(16);
            igniteConfiguration.setSystemThreadPoolSize(16);
            igniteConfiguration.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);


            ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);

            ignite.atomicLong("kafkaPartition", 0, true);
            ignite.atomicLong("startNodes", 0, true);

        } catch (IgniteException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + e.getCause().toString());
        }

        return ignite;
    }

private TcpDiscoverySpi getTcpDiscoverySpi() {
        var spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

        var kubConfiguration = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
        kubConfiguration.setNamespace("option-services");
        kubConfiguration.setServiceName("test-ignite-cache-service");

        var ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(kubConfiguration);
        spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        // set timeout properties
        spi.setAckTimeout(90000);
        spi.setSocketTimeout(90000);
        spi.setNetworkTimeout(90000);
        return spi;
    }

deploymentconfig.yaml
----------------------

apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: test-ignite-cache-standalone
  labels:
    app: test-ignite-cache-standalone
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    deploymentConfig: test-ignite-cache-standalone
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
    recreateParams:
      timeoutSeconds: 600
  triggers: [ ]
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-ignite-cache-standalone
      labels:
        deploymentConfig: test-ignite-cache-standalone
        app: test-ignite-cache-standalone
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 75
      serviceAccountName: test-ignite-cache-service
      containers:
        - name: test-ignite-cache-standalone
          image: {{ .Values.lsImageBase }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: JAVA_VM_OPTS
              value: "-Dspring.profiles.active={{ .Values.springProfile }}"
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.healthCheckEndpoint }}
              port: 8081
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 200
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: {{ .Values.healthCheckEndpoint }}
              port: 8081
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 200
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8081
              protocol: TCP
            - name: thinclient
              containerPort: 10800
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: {{ .Values.minMemory }}
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: {{ .Values.maxMemory }}
              cpu: "500m"



I am expecting to connect my server and client and talk each other how I am doing in my local using localhost addresses.
